# DOMParser for large html

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, domparser

I have a large amount of html clipboard data from Excel, about 250MB (though it contains a lot of formatting, so when actually pasting it in, the data is much, much smaller than that).

Currently I am using the following [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), which is just one line of code and everything happens behind the scenes:

```
const doc3 = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
```

However, it takes ~18s to parse this, and during this time the page is entirely blocking until it finishes -- *or, if offloaded to a webworker, an action that gives no progress and just 'waits' for 18s until something ends up happening -- which I would argue is almost the same as freezing even though yes the user can literally interact with the page*.

Is there an alternative way to parse a large html/xml file? Perhaps using something that doesn't load everything at once and so can be responsive, or what might be a good solution for this? I suppose the following might be inline with it? But not really sure: https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js.

---

Update: here is a sample Excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GIK7q_aU5tLuDNBVtlsDput8Oo1Ocz01/view?usp=sharing. You can download the file, open it in Excel, press Cmd-A (select-all), and Cmd-C (Copy), and it'll paste the data into your clipboard. For me copying it takes up 249MB for the text/html format in the clipboard.

Yes, it is also available in teext/plain (which we use as a backup), but the point of grabbing it from the text/html is to **capture the formatting** (both data formatting, for example numberType=Percent, 3 decimals and stylistic, for example, background color=red). Please use that as a test for any sample code. Here is the actual `test/html` content (in asci) when it's in the clipboard here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUL2A4Rlk3KPqO4vSSEEGBWuGXj7j5Vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes a stream xml parser can probably help. See [my comment here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/792#issuecomment-787698003). However you state you want to parse html, but xlsx is made of xml files, and html is a lot harder to parse than xml. So what are tou really trying to do? (Also, Workers don't have access to the DOMParser API anyway)

Comment: @Kaiido it's the html that is generated from copy-paste in Excel. Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/e3b061f3de6eeff0117867c8d7ac9102

Comment: Is it from the application "Numbers"? If so, this data is also accessible as tsv in the clipboard ("text/plain"), probably a lot easier to parse, and a lot smaller for the memory too. If it's Excel or an other app, I can't tell how they populate the clipboard, but might be worth checking for an alternative too.

Comment: @Kaiido it's from Excel, but yes Google Sheets or any other app should probably have a similar "output as text/html" format. Yes parsing text/plain is much simpler and is our fallback, but back to the question at hand...any way to parse it faster, or at least make it responsive :) ?

Comment: Well I mean parsing the TSV will be **much** faster than building up the DOM and parsing it from there. So don't make it your fallback, make it the main way to do this.

Comment: @Kaiido right but we need style information, the html contains lots of things the straight tsv doesn't.

Comment: If you're working with 250MB of excel data in the browser, generally that's a sign that your data should probably be in a different format. Could you edit your question to include what sort of application you're making, how you load the data (also does it have to come from the clipboard), and its use case? A database or reformatting your data might be a better solution.

Comment: sax.js looks like a pure JavaScript implementation, it’s an XML parser (not HTML), and unlike `DOMParser`, it doesn’t return a DOM tree (which you may or may not be able to adapt to).

Comment: Which one do you actually want to parse, HTML or XML, and do you actually need to parse the document into a DOM?

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated with a sample file.

Comment: Having the resulting html markup would probably be more useful, all softwares don't populate the clipboard the same way, on all platforms. Moreover when in your screenshot we can see your setup creates a `<style>` tag with rules that got to be matched against the elements below=> not only do you need an HTML parser and not just a simple XML one, but you also need a CSS parser and a CSSOM implementation. If I was in your position, I'd double check with the client if they'd be ok to either omit the styles when pasting big data, or force to send the XML file directly.

Comment: @Kaiido Updated with the clipboard html buffer.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Because I am sure there are better ways to do what you describe. From what I read I understand that you try to copy/paste big string and parse inside web browser. There are ways to do that with headless browser for sure. But there are also other formats that could be exported from the excel that could be converted to HTML tables as a second step.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is not `html` file size but the large number of DOM nodes it contains. For 900000 rows and 8 columns in your `html` file we have these figures:

**900000** (**TR** elements) * (**8** (**TD** elements) + **8** (**Text** nodes)) = **~14 millions** of DOM nodes!

I didn't manage to load it with `DOMParser`, browser tab crashes after a while (FF, Chrome, 16GB RAM), though it would be interesting to look at the browser behavior on successful load.
Anyway, I had a similar challenge, to handle millions of records in browser, the solution that I came up with was to build table rows only for one screen at time.

Considering the structure of your `text/html` file, the approach could be next:

> 1. use `FileReader` to load html file as raw text
> 2. grab rows, save them as text array, remove them from output
> 3. parse resulting output, insert the table and style into DOM
> 4. use a view / paging, render the current batch of rows on paging/scroll or search
> 5. attach events for mouse/keyboard control

Below is a simple implementation which provide basic controls like sizing view, paginate/scroll, filter rows with regular expressions. Note that filtering is done on row `html`, for `text` only search you can uncomment the line "*//text: text.match...*", though in this case the file parsing time will increase a bit.

```js
let tbody, style;
let rows = [], view = [], viewSize = 20, page = 0, time = 0;

const load = fRead => {
    console.timeEnd('FILE LOAD');
    console.time('GRAB ROWS');
    let thead, trows = '', table = fRead.result
        .replace(/<tr[^]+<\/tr>/i, text => (trows += text) && '');
    console.timeEnd('GRAB ROWS');
    console.time('PARSE/INSERT TABLE & STYLE');
    const html = document.createElement('div');
    html.innerHTML = table;
    table = html.querySelector('table');
    if (!table || !trows) {
        setInfo('NO DATA FOUND');
        return;
    }
    if (style = html.querySelector('style'))
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    table.textContent = '';
    el('viewport').appendChild(table);
    console.timeEnd('PARSE/INSERT TABLE & STYLE');
    console.time('PREPARE ROWS ARRAY');
    rows = trows.split('<tr').slice(1).map(text => ({
        html: '<tr' + text, text,
        //text: text.match(/>.*<\/td>/gi).map(s => s.slice(1, -5)).join(' '),
    }));
    console.timeEnd('PREPARE ROWS ARRAY');
    console.time('RENDER TABLE');
    table.appendChild(thead = document.createElement('thead'));
    table.appendChild(tbody = document.createElement('tbody'));
    thead.innerHTML = rows[0].html;
    view = rows = rows.slice(1);
    renew();
    console.timeEnd('RENDER TABLE');
    console.timeEnd('INIT');
};

const reset = info => {
    el('info').textContent = info ?? '';
    el('viewport').textContent = '';
    style?.remove();
    style = null;
    tbody = null;
    view = rows = [];
};

const pages = () => Math.ceil(view.length / viewSize) - 1;

const renew = () => {
    if (!tbody)
        return;
    console.time('RENDER VIEW');
    const i = page * viewSize;
    tbody.innerHTML = view.slice(i, i + viewSize)
        .map(row => row.html).join('');
    console.timeEnd('RENDER VIEW');
    setInfo(`
        rows total: ${rows.length},
        rows match: ${view.length},
        pages: ${pages()}, page: ${page}
    `);
};

const gotoPage = num => {
    el('page').value = page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages(), num));
    renew();
};

const fileInput = () => {
    reset('LOADING...');
    const fRead = new FileReader();
    fRead.onload = load.bind(null, fRead);
    console.time('INIT');
    console.time('FILE LOAD');
    fRead.readAsText(el('file').files[0]);
};

const fileReset = () => {
    reset();
    el('file').files = new DataTransfer().files;
};

const setInfo = text => el('info').innerHTML = text;

const setView = e => {
    let value = +e.target.value;
    value = Number.isNaN(value * 0) ? 20 : value;
    e.target.value = viewSize = Math.max(1, Math.min(value, 100));
    renew();
};

const setPage = e => {
    const page = +e.target.value;
    gotoPage(Number.isNaN(page * 0) ? 0 : page);
};

const setFilter = e => {
    const filter = e.target.value;
    let match;
    try {
        match = new RegExp(filter);
    } catch (e) {
        setInfo(e);
        return;
    }
    view = rows.filter(row => match.test(row.text));
    page = 0;
    renew();
};

const keys = {'PageUp': -1, 'PageDown': 1};

const scroll = e => {
    const dir = e.key ? keys[e.key] ?? 0 : Math.sign(-e.deltaY);
    if (!dir)
        return;
    e.preventDefault();
    gotoPage(page += dir);
};

const el = id => document.getElementById(id);

el('file').addEventListener('input', fileInput);
el('reset').addEventListener('click', fileReset);
el('view').addEventListener('input', setView);
el('page').addEventListener('input', setPage);
el('filter').addEventListener('input', setFilter);
el('viewport').addEventListener('keydown', scroll);
el('viewport').addEventListener('wheel', scroll);
```

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
thead td,
tbody tr td:first-child {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
}
td { padding: 0 .5em; }
#menu > * { margin: 0 .25em; }
#file { min-width: 16em; }
#view, #page { width: 8em; }
#filter { flex: 1; }
#info { padding: .5em; color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <span>FILE:</span>
        <input id="file" type="file" accept="text/html">
        <button id="reset">RESET</button>
    <span>VIEW:</span><input id="view" type="number" value="20">
    <span>PAGE:</span><input id="page" type="number" value="0">
    <span>FILTER:</span><input id="filter">
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="viewport" tabindex="0"></div>
```

As result, for **262 MB** html file (**900000** table rows) we have next timings in Chromium:

> *FILE LOAD*: 352.57421875 ms
>
> *GRAB ROWS*: 700.1943359375 ms
>
> *PARSE/INSERT TABLE & STYLE*: 0.78125 ms
>
> *PREPARE ROWS ARRAY*: 755.763916015625 ms
>
> *RENDER VIEW*: 0.926025390625 ms
>
> *RENDER TABLE*: 4.317138671875 ms
>
> **INIT**: 1814.19287109375 ms
>
> *RENDER VIEW*: 5.275146484375 ms
>
> *RENDER VIEW*: 4.6318359375 ms

So, the time till render of first batch of rows (time to screen) is `~1.8 s`, i.e. an order of magnitude lower than the time spent with `DOMParser` as specified by OP, subsequent rows render is almost instant: `~5 ms`

Comment: thanks for this. One question: `900000 (tr) * 8 (td) * 8 (text) `. What is "text" ?

Comment: "text" is the TextNode, i.e. actual text in one cell, `<tr[^]+` and `<tr[^>]*` will give the same output, the first variant matches also `>`

Comment: I see, but then why would `<td>text</td>` produce 8 dom nodes and not just one?

Comment: 1 row has 8 `td` nodes, each `td` node has 1 `text` node, i.e. 1 row is 17 DOM nodes

Comment: ok, so in javascript the following would have 8 DOM nodes and not 4? `<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr><tr><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>`

Comment: this `<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr><tr><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>` will be 10 DOM nodes

Comment: syduki -- ah that's tricky ok thanks for pointing that out. So basically with any text javascript will add an extra internal node for it?

Comment: that is the job of parser, I can't say for sure how many nodes it will insert, but there will be at least one TextNode for any text field

Comment: Probably the best strategy for OP (at least a lot better than the other answers). However there should be a big note that this is only for OP's particular case of parsing an HTML table, one can't parse arbitrary HTML files like that. Also note that it may fail to handle merged cells correctly. For instance you could have a <td> with a `rowspan` of 3 and split it in two different pages. In the second page, all the cells following the 'should-have-been-merged' cell would be in the wrong column: https://jsfiddle.net/p712k0de/

Comment: sure, this simple snippet doesn't pretend to full fledged all cases application, it is a hint how to do such things in a performant way, and which is adapted for this specific case. for more sophisticated layouts this could be views-in-views and much more lines of code :)

Comment: @syduki want to post some of the numbers and flesh out the answer a bit and I can award the bounty?

Comment: @Kaiido I see. Thanks for pointing that out. On a related clipboard note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785620/grabbing-partial-data-from-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: @carl.hiass added some numbers

Answer (score 2):

I’d at least try using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) as a parser. Unlike `DOMParser`, it’s asynchronous (so the webpage can be interacted with while loading is in progress), it’s capable of reporting progress and reading from [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects you get from [`Clipboard.read`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read), so the overhead of passing around large strings is also minimised.

Last I checked, however, this technique did not always work in all browsers, so don’t throw away `DOMParser` just yet, if only to have it as a fallback.

Besides `DOMParser` and `XMLHttpRequest`, the only native Web API providing DOM parsing functionality is [DOM Level 3 Load & Save](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-LS/), which as far as I am aware, no mainstream browser has ever implemented. This means `XMLHttpRequest` is basically your only option.

Here’s a quick-and-dirty example using `XMLHttpRequest` as a parser:

```
const parseHTML = (html, progress) => {
    let cleanup = null;
    let url;

    if (typeof Blob !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof html === 'string') {
            url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], { 'type': 'text/html' }));
        } else if (html instanceof Blob) {
            url = URL.createObjectURL(html);
        } else {
            throw new TypeError('html is neither a string nor a Blob');
        }
        cleanup = () => { URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }
    } else if (typeof html === 'string') {
        /* fallback to using data: URIs */
        url = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    } else {
        throw new TypeError('html is neither a string nor a Blob');     
    }
    
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html');
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
    
        xhr.onload = () => {
            accept(xhr.response || xhr.responseXML);
        };
        
        if (progress) {
            xhr.onprogress = (ev) => {
                /* percentage = ev.loaded / ev.total * 100;
                 * (beware of ev.total === 0)
                 */
                progress(ev);
            };
        }
        
        /* XXX: if the promise is awaited, this makes it
         * throw a ProgressEvent on failure, which is…
         * unusual, though workable */
        xhr.onabort = xhr.onerror = (ev) => {
            reject(ev);
        };
        
        xhr.onloadend = cleanup;
        
        xhr.send(null);
    });
};
```

When I tested this myself, performance was less than stellar, though somewhat bearable (after the file was loaded, parsing itself took about half a minute, during which the browser was rather unresponsive). I also noticed this would occasionally return `null` for the empty string, so beware of that as well.

Comment: Did you actually tried it? Here with a 60MB xml it just fails on my Chrome with response set to the empty string and responseXML set to null.

Comment: I tried it on **HTML**. On Firefox, for what it’s worth.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if it's HTML or XML, only the size & browser matters.

Comment: Ps: trying it now on FF, it freezes the browser just like the DOMParser does. (which makes sense since it's not supposed to use an other thread even though it's an async operation)

Comment: Whether it uses a separate thread for parsing or not is an implementation detail invisible to the site, so it might be transparently implemented in the future. That it isn’t yet – tough luck. But with `DOMParser`, there is not even a possibility of that happening.

Comment: ... I wouldn't bet a dime on that no. XHR has been suplemented by fetch, don't expect any improvement in that area. Also your claim that these are the only native web APIs providing DOM parsing is wrong. `innerHTML` is an obvious one, Range.createContextualFragment is an other one and it's possible other specs have their own (like SVG's foreignObject and the like)

Comment: Providing whole-document DOM parsing. `foreignObject` is not an API. And the others are synchronous anyway, they are `DOMParser` with extra steps.

Comment: Yes I never said they aren't synchronous nor any better than a DOMParser. By the way regarding [responseXML](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responsexml-attribute) the parsing is done in  the getter and it must also be done synchronously. So this solution doesn't work in the most popular browser, duplicates the full data in memory, and is as blocking as OP's current solution...

Comment: @user3840170 I've added a sample test file, could you please see if your code works with that?