# Grabbing partial data from the clipboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, clipboard

I have copied an Excel table which is about a million rows. When I look at the clipboard on my system, it seems to contain about 250MB of data. However, I **only** need to grab the styling information from it, for example:

[image]

This entire data comes out to (far) less than 1MB of data. Is there a way to read the clipboard as if it were a file or stream, so that I can just do, for example:

```
clipboard.read(1024)
```

Otherwise, if I do the straight:

```
evt.clipboardData.getData('text/html')
```

And grab the section of data I want **after** getting the data, it takes me over 10 seconds to do! Whereas I believe the event should only take 0.1s or so, if I'm able to read the clipboard data in a partial manner, as if it were a file.

What can I do here? Is it possible to use `FileReader` on the clipboard? If so, how could that be done?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: @ultra_rn how does that solve anything? I'm already grabbing the data directly from the `ClipboardData` event. If it solves the question do you want to post an answer showing how that allows reading partial data from the clipboard?

Comment: @ultra_rn also, this takes no parameters, and so you cannot specify number of bytes to parse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Clipboard.read`](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#dom-clipboard-read) API cited in the comments can return clipboard contents as a list of [`ClipboardItem`](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboarditem) objects, from which you can then obtain a [`Blob`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) object, which you can then [`.slice`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-slice) to perform partial reads.

```js
const perm = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-read' });
switch (perm.state) {
case 'granted':
case 'prompt':
    break;
default:
    throw new Error("clipboard-read permission not granted");
}

const items = await navigator.clipboard.read();
for (const item of items) {
    const blob = await item.getType('text/html');
    const first1M = await blob.slice(0, 1048576).arrayBuffer();
    
    /* process first1M */
}
```

However, the Clipboard API is nowhere near universally available as of yet. Firefox ESR 78.9 doesn’t implement it. (I haven’t tried other browsers yet; perhaps in Chrome it’s already usable.)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot a research, this is not possible in `Javascript`, there is no support for `stream` manipulation using the clipboard object so u have to read the entire content at once.

However, u can use `MacOS` (inferred from your picture) native tools for processing the clipboard data: `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`, and they are extremely fast, orders of magnitude faster than `Javascript`, so u can delegate the heavy processing of the text to them.

So, after u copy the 250MB of text, you can slice it and read only the first `n` bytes (in this case 1024) and substitute the content of the clipboard with that, so now u it will be available for u to use it in `Javascript`:

```
pbpaste | cut -b 1-1024 | pbcopy
```

If u need any documentation about each terminal command, u can run `man command_name`. Extracting the first 1024 bytes of the clipboard took less than a second with this approach.

I tested it with a sample text file of 390MB created with `python` with this script:

```
c = 30000000

with open('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('a sample code' for i in range(c))
```

Comment: right, unfortunately the user has the data and it's a browser app so it needs to be in js !